# How to put file name into a field using R

Tags: r

I use the code `aa <- read.csv("W:/project/data4try1.csv")` to read a file into `aa` data frame.
I want to create a new field (say: `filename`) in `aa` to hold the file name `"data4try1"` (exclude ".csv") for each rows.
it looks like:

```r
filename, var1, var2
data4try1,123,456
data4try1,001,abc
data4try1,bc,786
```

Comment: I will read many files later. and then combine them into one large data frame. So, I need to know each row from which file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-off, do it like this:

```
filepath = "W:/project/data4try1.csv""W:/project/data4try1.csv"
filename = basename(filepath)
filename_no_ext = sub(pattern = "\\.[^\\.]+$", replacement = "", filename)

aa <- read.csv(filepath)
aa$filename = filename_no_ext
```

Depending on your use case, you could turn this into a function:

```
read.csv.addpath = function(filepath, ...) {
  filename = basename(filepath)
  filename_no_ext = sub(pattern = "\\.[^\\.]+$", replacement = "", filename)

  data <- read.csv(filepath, ...)
  data$filename = filename_no_ext
  return(data)
}
```

You might do better to use `list.files` to generate a vector of all filenames and read them all at once, see [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for examples of that. If you use `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows` on a named list of data frames, they can add the filename column for you based on the names of the list.

Comment: Hello Gregor, it works perfect. thank you. one more question, could you explain what's that mean of the string following the pattern: sub(pattern = "\\.[^\\.]+$", replacement = "", filename)? I would like to learn that and don't ask the kind of question again.

Comment: That's regular expressions (regex). My goal is to match the last `.` in the string, and everything after it. This is a pretty tricky regex for a beginner, but `.` is special in regex, it normally means "any single character". To make it a literal `.`, I escape it with `\\`. So `\\.` matches a `.`. Then, I want to match everything *except* a `.` until the end of the string. Inside brackets, `^` means "not", so `[^\\.]` means "not a `.`" (escaping the `.` as above). The `+` is a quantifier, which modifies the "not a `.`" to mean "one or more", and `$` anchors at the end of the string.

Comment: All of that complication is to make sure it would work even if your file names contained `.`, so `my.great.file.csv` would turn into `my.great.file` rather than just `my`.

Comment: Congrats on 100k, GregorThomas!